# How do I achieve a flex layout with centered elements but without space-between/around?

Tags: css, flexbox

Basically, how do I achieve this layout while having equal spacing on both left and right sides? Space-between and space-around do not seem to work because the remaining elements at the bottom are then either centered or on both sides of the container.

[image]

Comment: `flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: space-around;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-wrap`:

```
flex-wrap: nowrap; /* Default value */
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;

/* Global values */
flex-wrap: inherit;
flex-wrap: initial;
flex-wrap: unset;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap